# Fxcomponent: Flex video player issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I'm using the fxcomponent: [Flv video player](http://www.fxcomponents.com/item/about-us/29/) to play my flv/mob files.

You may get it from [here](http://www.brothersoft.com/flex-video-player-340203.html).

Now, player works perfectly as shown in their site, but when I try to use the `FXVideo` control in popup window (popup manager help is [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_12.html)), the component gives mirror image!, strange, I didn't change any code in that.

So can any one help me out to fix this issue, as I'm novice to action script?

Image:

[image]

For quick set up, I'm putting my code here:

1. FXVideo_Example.mxml file (No change at all except variable)

   ```
           [Bindable]
           private var source:String = "http://localhost/greatcatches.flv";

           ]]>
   </mx:Script>
   <controls:FXVideo width="480" height="360" source="{source}" autoPlay="false" bufferTime="10" />
   ```
2. MainPage.mxml:

   ```
           import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
           import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

           private function showW():void {
               // Create a non-modal TitleWindow container.
               var helpWindow:IFlexDisplayObject =
                   PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, FXVideo_Example, false);
           }
       ]]>
   </mx:Script>

   <mx:VBox width="480" height="360">  
       <mx:Button click="showW();" label="Show"/>
   </mx:VBox>
   ```

Comment: looks like editor's code format is not working correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up by using spark component!

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="videoPlayer"
   source="http://localhost/greatcatches.flv"
   autoRewind="true"
   muted="true"
   horizontalCenter="0"
   verticalCenter="0" />
```